# Create dynamic installer package on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, wix, setup-project

First of all what the installer should do:

1. Check if .NET 4.0 is a requirement
2. Unpack files
3. Generate configuration for specified user
4. Install windows service
5. Start windows service

The only problem which I have is "3" (Generate configuration for specified user).

I found following solution:

1. Create setup project
2. "Decompile" msi using MSI2XML and create "template" from decompiled installer
3. When user try to download installer on my site use XML2MSI to build installer package from "template"

The server-side technlogy is ASP.NET MVC (but MVC in this case probably does not matter), also I hosting my project on Azure (this is probably much bigger problem).

So my questions are:

1. Can I do this in above way?
2. Is there a better solution?
3. Should I use WiX instead of setup project (2012 does not support setup project)?

Comment: What kind of configurations are you doing that require a custom install file for each client?

Comment: I was hoping for creating simple installer without entering user and pass then create custom action which will validate it, etc. In my opinion it would be much more easier if installer will be setup for user

Comment: WIX would allow you to create a step in the installer that could call your own service to validate users and passwords.  But you wont get that with setup project.

Comment: Could you give me link to such tutorial?